# Is it possible to calculate total based on data in another cell?

Tags: ms-access

I want to count Total of Score based on the Grade. Example of table as below:
[image]

I want to do this in Access Report but not sure how to calculate it in Expression Builder. Please help.

Comment: Please provide the structure of the underlying tables, and specify which cell is a problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use expressions like:

```
=Abs(Sum([Grade-Math]="A"))
=Abs(Sum([Grade-Math]="B"))

=Abs(Sum([Grade-Science]="A"))
=Abs(Sum([Grade-Science]="B"))
```